# Splitting single row into multiple based on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have certain number of rows as below:

```
| Material No   | Quantity | Weight | Unit |
--------------------------------------------
| 111-22283/4   |    2     |   53   |  kg  |
| 123-ABC45/7   |    5     |   41   |   g  |
| 133-67879/80  |    7     |   31   |   g  |
| 144-54628     |    1     |   14   |  kg  |
```

Now I want to produce output like below:

```
| Material No   | Quantity | Weight | Unit |
--------------------------------------------
| 111-22283     |    2     |   53   |  kg  |
| 111-22284     |    2     |   53   |  kg  |
| 123-ABC45     |    5     |   41   |   g  |
| 123-ABC46     |    5     |   41   |   g  |
| 123-ABC47     |    5     |   41   |   g  |
| 133-67879     |    7     |   31   |   g  |
| 133-67880     |    7     |   31   |   g  |
| 144-54628     |    1     |   14   |  kg  |
```

**Logic**: Based on the material no I have to split the rows. If '/' at end of the material no then it needs to be spilt. Then we have to find the difference b/w last number in the material no and the number /. If it is `2` then I want 2 different rows with each number as material number(*Means if the last digit is 83/4 then I want material number ends with 83 and 84*). The tricky part is when we are having 89/90. It will contain 2 number after / (*only for 10's,20's etc.,*). All other column will remain as same for each material no.

To achieve this ,currently we have a very big procedure which contains around 50-80 lines of code( find the row with '/' and remove separately then find the index of / and so on). I would like to know if this can be done with simple query or a very short procedure.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: is the `Material No` always in fix format `???-?????` Only numeric ?

Comment: @Squirrel yes, most of the time it will be in fixed format only. No it can be alpha numeric

Comment: @Fourat. As i mentioned in the question we have a big procedure which contains several steps to acheive this.  I can't paste the whole procedure here as it contains 80 lines.

Comment: Try a `cross apply` with an "Inline Table Valued Function" containing a recursive `CTE` which is passed the `material no` and splits the strings out for you.

Comment: If you have alpha characters too, include those in your sample as well. Strings and numbers order completely differently, so we need to understand things like if `'b' > '2'` and if `'3' > '12'`.

Comment: I would suggest you to use SSIS instead of pure SQL Query. You should separate that number duplication data and pure key of material no to temp table and insert new rows maybe using small .NET program or Script task at SSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the challenging part is probably splitting the `material no` to get the `starting` and `ending` number.

After that, it is just a simple recursive query to increment the number and concatenate back to form the material no.

```
;with rcte as
(
    select  MaterialNo,
            base, st, en, n = st,
            material    = convert(varchar(20), base + isnull(convert(varchar(10), st), ''))
    from    material m
            -- get the position of the `/`
            cross apply
            (
                select  split = charindex('/', MaterialNo)          
            ) s     
            -- extract the ending number and convert to integer
            cross apply
            (
                select  en  = case  when    split > 0
                                    then    convert(int, right(MaterialNo, len(MaterialNo) -  split))
                                    end     
            ) en
            -- extract the starting number and convert to integer
            cross apply
            (
                select  st  = case  when    split > 0
                        then    convert(int, substring(MaterialNo, split - len(en), len(en)))
                        end
            ) st
            -- extract the base material no for concatenate
            cross apply
            (
                select  base    = case  when    split   > 0
                                        then    left(MaterialNo, split - len(en) - 1)
                                        else    MaterialNo
                                        end
            ) b

    union all

    select  MaterialNo, base, st, en, 
            n = n + 1,
            material = convert(varchar(20), base + convert(varchar(10), n + 1))
    from    rcte 
    where   n < en
)
select  *
from    rcte
order by MaterialNo, material
```

all this is based on the assumption that the ending of material no is purely numeric.

Note : if you have a tally table, you can use that to replace the recursive cte

Comment: Thanks @squirrel. I will check this with all scenarios and accept the answer soon

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

When a value from `MATERIALNO` can represent a series of values (as the updated question) :

DDL

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION UFN_STRTOSERIES (@materialNo VARCHAR(80), @qte INT, @weight INT, @unit VARCHAR(50))  
RETURNS @result TABLE (
  MATERIALNO VARCHAR(80),
  QTE INT,
  Weight INT,
  UNIT VARCHAR(50)
)
AS  
BEGIN
  DECLARE @base VARCHAR(50) = LEFT(@materialNo,CHARINDEX('/',@materialNo)-1-LEN(RIGHT(@materialNo,LEN(@materialNo)-CHARINDEX('/',@materialNo))));
  DECLARE @start INT = CONVERT( INT , RIGHT( LEFT(@materialNo,CHARINDEX('/',@materialNo)-1) , LEN(RIGHT(@materialNo,LEN(@materialNo)-CHARINDEX('/',@materialNo))) ) );
  DECLARE @end INT = CONVERT( INT , RIGHT(@materialNo,LEN(@materialNo)-CHARINDEX('/',@materialNo)) );

  DECLARE @i INT = @start;
  WHILE @i <= @end
  BEGIN
    INSERT @result  
    SELECT CONCAT(@base,@i) AS MATERIALNO, @qte, @weight, @unit;
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END;

  RETURN
END;

CREATE TABLE MATERIALS
(
  MATERIALNO VARCHAR(80),
  QTE INT,
  Weight INT,
  UNIT VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO MATERIALS VALUES
('111-22283/4',2,53,'kg'),
('123-33345/7',5,41,'g' ),
('123-ABC45/7',5,41,'g'),
('133-67879/80',7,31,'g'),
('144-54628',1,14,'kg')
```

DML

```sql
SELECT MATERIALNO,QTE,Weight,UNIT
FROM (
SELECT MATERIALNO,QTE,Weight,UNIT
FROM MATERIALS
WHERE CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO) < 1
UNION
SELECT series.MATERIALNO,series.QTE,series.Weight,series.UNIT
FROM MATERIALS m
CROSS APPLY UFN_STRTOSERIES(MATERIALNO,QTE,Weight,UNIT) series
WHERE CHARINDEX('/',m.MATERIALNO) > 1
) base
ORDER BY base.MATERIALNO
```

**OLD ANSWER**

When a value from `MATERIALNO` represents **only** two values :

`UNION` is the easiest answer (then you have to check performances) :

DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE MATERIALS
(
  MATERIALNO VARCHAR(80),
  QTE INT,
  Weight INT,
  UNIT VARCHAR(50)
 )

 INSERT INTO MATERIALS VALUES
('111-22283/4',2,53,'kg'),
('123-33345/7',5,41,'g' ),
('133-67879/80',7,31,'g'),
('144-54628',1,14,'kg'  )
```

Query

```sql
SELECT MATERIALNO,QTE,Weight,UNIT
FROM (
SELECT MATERIALNO,QTE,Weight,UNIT
FROM MATERIALS
WHERE CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO) < 1
UNION
SELECT LEFT(MATERIALNO,CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO)-1),QTE,Weight,UNIT
FROM MATERIALS
WHERE CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO) > 1
UNION
SELECT 
CONCAT(LEFT(MATERIALNO,CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO)-1-LEN(RIGHT(MATERIALNO,LEN(MATERIALNO)-CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO)))),RIGHT(MATERIALNO,LEN(MATERIALNO)-CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO))) AS MATERIALNO
,QTE,Weight,UNIT
FROM MATERIALS
WHERE CHARINDEX('/',MATERIALNO) > 1
) BASE
ORDER BY BASE.MATERIALNO
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e768/2

Comment: Thanks Fourat. But For 2nd row i should get 3 rows(ending with 45,46,47), but here only 2 rows are coming.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy you edited your question and I didn't see it, I will edit my answer